# Find the work required to displace a particle along the ellipse $ x^2 + \frac{y^2}{b^2}= 1 $ against the force $ F (x , y) = (3y^2 + 2, 16x) $.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the work required to displace a particle from point $ (1, 0) $ to $ (- 1, 0) $ along the ellipse $ x^2 + \frac{y^2}{b^2}= 1 $ against the force $ F (x , y) = (3y^2 + 2, 16x) $.

I have this problem, my question is that now we have that we want the particle to move against a force $F$, if we did not want to go against F, it would be enough to give a parameterization $ \alpha $ and integrate but how we want to go against of the force then we must give a reparametrization of F with the opposite sense to that of alpha and integrate?

Answer (score 0):

write the work function as
$dw= [(3y^2+2)i+16xj].[dxi+dyj]$    as $dw=f.ds$ and $s= x^2+y^2/b^2-1$ and so from differentiating s with x and y basically you will get an expression as$ xdx=-ydy/b^2$.....(1) .

then $dw=(3y^2+2)dx + (16x)dy$ then , first make $dy$ from $dx$ by $eq(1)$ in 1st part of $dw$ similarly apply the same concept in snd part of it then

$dw = [-y(3y^2+2)/b(b^2-y^2)^1/2]dy + [-16bx^2/(1-x^2)^0.5]dx$ hence integrate y function from 0 to 0 and x function from 1 to -1  along ellispe to get the answer.

MY evaluated answer = $8*3.14*b$ in magnitude and work is released by sense.